# Auto Mount NTFS Drive at /media/user/Data x at each user login?

Tags: 16.04, mount, hard-drive, files, ntfs

I am using Ubuntu OS [details here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzHQg.png)
I am using Files as File Manger which is [details here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PVnF.png)

The NTFS drive names of the system are "Data 1" and "Data 2".

These drives mount to /media/user/Data 1 and /media/user/Data 2 only when

I click on Below "Data 1" and "Data 2" names on files left the panel [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06zcR.png).

I want to be automated this mount at the same location.

Any suggestion will be also helpful.

Thank You,
VK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install "ntfs-config"

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-config
```

After installation, Run below command in the terminal,

```
 sudo ntfs-config
```

Now, Choose the drive which you wanna to mount.